# Using amfphp with Flash CS3 and AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, remoting, amfphp

All,

I've starting experimenting with amfphp. I've gone through a few great tutorials (particularly those by Lee Brimlow at gotoandlearn.com).

As long as you're using AS3, it works great, since AS3 includes the built-in NetConnection class.

However, I'm looking to use amfphp on a bunch of existing AS2 projects.

The problem is that AS2 doesn't seem to have a NetConnection class, but Adobe's remoting components only work for Flash 8, not CS3.

A google search turned up a bunch of suggestions that I copy files from my Flash 8 installation to CS3, but I don't have Flash 8.

Am I stuck? Is there a way to work around this?

Many thanks in advance for any advice or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the as2 Remoting Components for flash 8 for the [MAC](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashremoting/flash8/flashremoting_components_flash8.dmg) and [PC](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashremoting/flash8/flashremoting_components_flash8.msi) on the Adobe website. It might not install in the right folder for Flash CS3, but there are the mx.remoting classes that go in the same folder with your other as2 mx packages the NetConnection Debugger that goes in the WindowSWF folder and the swc themselves that go in Common Libraries.

I have the classes at the office, not home, where I am now, so I'm not 100% accurate.

I remember there were some handy video tutorials on as2 on the [amfphp website](http://amfphp.org/videotuts.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't do any as2 programming myself, but this posting http://drupal.org/node/258605#comment-852450 looks like it has a download for the classes you need.

You could also try to combine as2 and as3 by loading a separate as3 swf and communicating via the LocalConnection http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1964550#post1964550 but I'd guess that removes almost all the benefits of amfphp.